# Cascading merge of git release branches in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

Recently my project has moved from Bitbucket to Azure DevOps for hosting our git repositories. One feature we have been relying on is the automatic cascading merging of release branches. That means whenever a pull request is merged into one of our release branches, the merge is automatically cascading so the target release branch gets merged to their downstream branches. I.e. release branches with a higher release number.

**Example:** I have a pull request that is merged from my own bugfix branch into branch "release/1.2". Because we're working simultaneously on a patch release we also have another release branch "release/1.2.1". When my pull request is merged into "release/1.2" Bitbucket will automatically try to merge "release/1.2" into "release/1.2.1". Of course, if there's a merge conflict, Bitbucket will instead create a pull request highlighting that it cannot merge automatically and someone needs to fix the conflict before it can be merged.

We have not been able to find a way to do something similar in Azure DevOps, so my question is: **Is it possible?**

Alternatively, a solution that goes some of the way would also be acceptable so we avoid having to manually remember merging once in a while, as well as avoiding huge merges because a lot of changes have accumulated.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Devops does not have such feature to automatically merge two branches due to your pull request.

But you could use pipeline to realize it. Instead, use pipeline to [create a pull request with reset api for your bugfix branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318377/azdo-to-pull-into-2-different-remote-target-branches-at-same-time) and then use git merge task or [use batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982127/merging-one-branch-to-another-through-vsts-api).